# Regex re.findall() hangs - What if you cant read line by line

Tags: python, regex, freeze

I have multiple files, each of which I am searching for a sequence of words.

My regex expression basically searches for a sequence where word1 is followed by word2 followed by word 3 etc..
So the expression looks like:

```
strings = re.findall('word1.*?word2.*?word3', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

For files below 20kb, the expression executes pretty well. However, the execution time exponentially increases for files > 20 kb and the process completely hangs for files close to 100kb.
It appears (after having read previous threads) that the problem is to do with using .* in conjunction with re.DOTALL - leading to "catastrophic backtracking". The recommended solution was to provide the input file line by line instead of reading the whole file into a single memory buffer.

However, my input file is filled with random whitespace and "\n" newline characters. My word sequence is also long and occurs over multiple lines. Therefore, I need to input the whole file together into the regex expression in conjunction with re.DOTALL - otherwise a line by line search will never find my sequence.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: try doingthis in f.readlines(), and regex it line by line

Comment: @karthikr How is that possible if the whole thing is filled with random whitespace and newlines?

Comment: I thought f.read() is a file read

Comment: The problem is that if I regex it line by line, the search will never find my sequence - my sequence doesnt occur in a single line...but only over multiple lines because of the presence of random "\n" chars

Comment: I have tried splitting the file into complete sentences by writing a manual code that weeds out all fullstops which might be part of abbreviations etc.. and then feeding each full sentence into the regex search..and thats giving me slightly better results.

Comment: How about using plain string operations? Get the index of `word1`, `word2` and `word3` and then check these indices?

Answer (score 2):

If you're literally searching for the occurrence of three words, with no regex patterns in them at all, there's no need to use regexes at all – as suggested by @Bart as I wrote this answer :). Something like this might work (untested, and can probably be prettier):

```
with open('...') as f:
    contents = f.read()

words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
matches = []
start_idx = 0
try:
    while True:
        cand = []
        for word in words:
            word_idx = contents.index(word, start_idx)
            cand.append(word_idx)
            start_idx = word_idx + len(word)
        matches.append(cand)
except ValueError:  # from index() failing
    pass
```

This puts the indices in `matches`; if you want an equivalent result to findall, you could do, say,

```
found = [contents[match[0]:match[-1]+len(words[-1]] for match in matches]
```

You could also make this kind of approach work without reading the whole file in beforehand by replacing the call to `index` with an equivalent function on files. I don't think the stdlib includes such a function; you'd probably have to manually use `readline()` and `tell()` or similar methods on file objects.

Comment: Yes, a far better option than regex in this case.

Comment: While this may be correct, it is extremely verbose, and impossible to tell what it does at a glance. It can be used as an exercise, but really shouldn't be used in production for this use case.

Comment: @SergiuToarca, Python reads much like pseudo-code. Personally, I'd opt for a (documented) version of this over a regex solution in production. Especially if that regex engine isn't provided in the core language, I'd for for the built-in `find`. All IMHO, of course.

Comment: @SergiuToarca NFA-based regexes are great, and I +1ed your answer, but sometimes you can't add a dependency, or it's not worthwhile. I'd also argue that 15 lines of fairly simple code for a nontrivial task plus some comments doesn't count as "extremely verbose." :)

Comment: Agreed, though I still maintain that it's overly verbose :p

Comment: The equivalent of findall would rather be `[contents[match[0]:match[-1]+len(words[-1])] for match in matches]`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because python's regex engine uses backtracking. At every `.*`, if the following word is not found, the engine must go all the way to the end of the string (100kb) and then backtrack. Now consider what happens if there are many "almost matches" after the last match. The engine keeps jumping back and forth from the start of the match to the end of the string.

You can fix it by using a regex engine based on an NFA rather than backtracking. Note that this limits the kinds of regexes you can use (no backtracking or arbitrary zero-width assertions), but it's fine for your use case.

You can find such an engine [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/). You can visualize how an nfa engine works at [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=word1.%2a?word2.%2a?word3&str=word1%20word3%20word2%20word3%20word1%20word3word1%20word2%20word1%20word%202word3%20word1%20word2%20word2).

Comment: In the worst case, the entire file has no matches, so yes.

Comment: I used the phrasing "when it doesn't find the following word", but I'll change it to be more clear.

Comment: It would fail only when it gets to the end of the word, then backtrack to any other paths it could take, eventually getting to the start of the match. Then it would continue from there until it finds another "start of the match". Think through what happens if the end of my file looks like `word1 word1 word1`.

Comment: No, it will only fail after trying to match from every possible start position.

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it some more, and after reading your edited answer (the *many "almost matches"*-part), I think you're right. I already mentioned it, but I'll say it again: neat tool!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to search for one word at a time. I'm using `str.find()` here as it is faster for simple substring search, but you can also adapt this code to work with `re.search()` instead.

```
def findstrings(text, words):
    end = 0
    while True:
        start = None
        for word in words:
            pos = text.find(word, end) #starts from position end
            if pos < 0:
                return
            if start is None:
                start = pos
            end = pos + len(word)
        yield text[start:end]


#usage in place of re.findall('word1.*?word2.*?word3', f.read(), re.DOTALL)
list(findstrings(f.read(), ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']))
```